# Traveling to China transfer in Hong Kong. Do I need a HK transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, hong-kong, iranian-citizens

I'm an Iranian citizen planning to go to China from Europe. I already have the visa for China. I will go through HK to Hangzhou and then will return from Tokyo again through HK to Europe.
Do I need a transit visa for Hong Kong?

Comment: I've seen that question but that one does not specify the destination of the flight to be China. my destination is China and I already have a visa for China.

Comment: I see your point, the answer should not change in Hong Kong's case even if your final destination is China and have a Chinese visa. I've put an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The list provided by [Hong Kong Immigration Department](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html#notes) states Iranian citizens will need a visa even for transit:

> IRAN (please see remarks)   -   Visa Required*
>
> *All nationals are required to hold a valid visa for the HKSAR for whatever purpose (including those who are in transit and remain on the airside).

For completeness, if you also hold one of the following documents you are not required to have a valid visa:

> No visa or entry permit is required for any purpose if you hold any of the following travel documents:
>
> - Hong Kong Special Administrative Region Passport,
> - British National (Overseas) Passport,
> - Hong Kong Certificate of Identity,
>   [...]
> - Hong Kong Document of Identity for Visa Purposes provided that the document is valid or the holder's limit of stay in Hong Kong has not expired.
> - Travel documents bearing one of the following endorsements:
>
>   - "Holder's eligibility for Hong Kong permanent identity card verified."
>   - "The holder of this travel document has the right to land in Hong Kong. (Section 2AAA, Immigration Ordinance, Cap. 115, Laws of Hong Kong)"
> - Hong Kong Permanent Identity Card.

Hong Kong operates a separate immigration system to China under the [One country, two systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_country,_two_systems) principle. Having a Chinese visa does not exempt one from the need of a Hong Kong visa, should they need one.